# yield as opposed to while True: yield usage in python

Tags: python, sqlite, generator, yield, coroutine

I wanted to build a helper function to get query results from sqlite, to use for comparison with results from another database.

I wanted the user to have a simple interface, where he calls the function with his query and gets a result, without any other preparation.

I ended up writing 2 functions:

```
import sqlite3 
.
.
def sqlite_query_executor(query):
    conn=sqlite3.connect(':memory:')
    cur=conn.cursor()

    yield cur.execute(query).fetchall()[0][0]
```

And the one meant to be called by the user:

```
def query_sqlite(query):

    return next(sqlite_query_executor(query))
```

While tinkering with the first function, I initially wrote another version with a slightly different ending:

```
def sqlite_query_executor(query):
    conn=sqlite3.connect()
    cur=conn.cursor()

    while True:
        yield cur.execute(query).fetchall()[0][0]
```

Both versions seemed to work well, but I'm struggling with the mechanics.

Could someone perhaps shed light on the difference? What is the correct pattern for such usecase?

Comment: the first function connects at every iteration. This seems very underperformant.

Comment: So the cursor just stays connected the whole time? Don't you have to close the connection?

Comment: Why did you bother with all this `yield` and `next` stuff, and `fetchall` when you don't actually want *all*?

Comment: @CoryMadden It's for a test suite, I assume if it's called, it'll be called a bunch.

Comment: @user2357112 It's a single query that yields one result, I guess a regular fetch works just as well

Comment: @Jean-FrançoisFabre Thanks, I realize the while version is the correct one

Comment: @Jean-FrançoisFabre: Either way, `query_sqlite` just calls `sqlite_query_executor` again every time and only `next`s the result once, so it's connecting every time anyway.

Comment: @Jean-FrançoisFabre Does it matter that `query_sqlite` gets closed and reopened? I assumed that `sqlite_query_executor` takes a permanent hold in memory, and just bounces back results every time you say its name.

Answer (score 1):

The *fetchall()* does too much work and should be replaced with *fetchone()*:

```
def sqlite_query_executor(query):
    conn=sqlite3.connect()
    cur=conn.cursor()

    while True:
        yield cur.execute(query).fetchone()[0]
```